# DELETE method on a Handlebars template button

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js

Trying to figure out how to delete an entry on a mongodb/mongoose/node database. I know how to create an entry by using the POST method on a form submit button. But its hard to find anything on how to DELETE on a method using a submit button. I know you cant use "DELETE" on html forms but is the other alternative?

Route on Node

```
router.delete('/:id',function(req, res, next){
  Docket.findById(req.params.id, function(err, docket){
    docket.remove(function(err){
      res.redirect('/dockets');
    });
  });
});
```

Handlebars template

```
<form name="delete-docket-form" id="delete-docket-form" method="delete">
    <div class="form-submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete my docket" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can use POST and action="/123456?method=delete" as a workaround, but this would need router.post instead of router.delete and then you need to check req.query.method == 'delete'. Or use jQuery Ajax with a button $.ajax({type: 'DELETE',url:'/123456',...

Comment: You mean: action="{{this.id}}?method=delete" and Docket.findById(req.query.method == delete, function(err, docket) {  ??

Comment: Yes action="{{this.id}}?method=delete" is correct but Docket.findById requires an id, why are you passing req.query.method == delete ?? So in your router.post...You just check `if(req.query.method == delete){ Docket.findById(id,... docket.remove... } else { // if the delete is not specified use this route as you would normaly} So you simply use one route for two things.

Comment: Thanks man, I got it!!